# EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found. - NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Yes, I know that there are tons of questions like this, but I can't seem to fix this even after going through 20 posts with the same error.

I am using NestJS config.

**Error Message**

[image: Full error message]

**User entity (located in src/entities)**

```
import { Item } from './item.entity';
import { Rent } from './rent.entity';
import { Review } from './review.entity';
import { Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  surname: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  street: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 50 })
  city: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 5 })
  zip: string;

  @Column({ type: 'int', nullable: true })
  rating: number;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 10 })
  phone: string;

  @Column('date')
  date: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 50, nullable: false, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 75, nullable: false })
  password: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Review, (review) => review.user)
  reviews: Review[];

  @OneToMany(() => Rent, (rent) => rent.user)
  rents: Rent[];

  @OneToMany(() => Item, (item) => item.user)
  items: Item[];
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { configValidationSchema } from './config.schema';
import { ConfigOption } from './config-option';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { Review } from './entities/review.entity';
import { Rent } from './entities/rent.entity';
import { Item } from './entities/item.entity';
import { Category } from './entities/category.entity';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
      validationSchema: configValidationSchema,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          type: 'postgres',
          host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
          port: Number(configService.get('DB_PORT')),
          username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
          password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
          database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
          entities: [join(__dirname, '**', '*.entity.{ts,js}')],
          migrations: [__dirname, '**', '*{.ts,.js}'],
          synchronize: false,
          cli: {
            entitiesDir: 'src/entities',
            migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
          },
        };
      },
    }),
    AuthModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**config validation schema**

```
import * as Joi from '@hapi/joi';

export const configValidationSchema = Joi.object({
  DB_HOST: Joi.string().required(),
  DB_PORT: Joi.number().default(5432).required(),
  DB_USERNAME: Joi.string().required(),
  DB_PASSWORD: Joi.string().required(),
  DB_DATABASE: Joi.string().required(),
  JWT_SECRET: Joi.string().required(),
});
```

**auth.module.ts (module where i use User entity)**

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersRepository } from './users.repository';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigService, ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
        signOptions: {
          expiresIn: 3600,
        },
      }),
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UsersRepository]),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [JwtStrategy, PassportModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**Users Repository**

```
import {
  ConflictException,
  InternalServerErrorException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { SignUpDto } from './dto/signup.dto';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@EntityRepository(User)
export class UsersRepository extends Repository<User> {
  async createUser(signUpDto: SignUpDto): Promise<void> {
    const {
      name,
      surname,
      street,
      city,
      zip,
      rating,
      phone,
      date,
      email,
      password,
    } = signUpDto;

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const user = this.create({
      name,
      surname,
      street,
      city,
      zip,
      rating,
      phone,
      date,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });
    try {
      await this.save(user);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === '23505') {
        throw new ConflictException('User with the same e-mail already exists');
      } else {
        console.log(error);
        throw new InternalServerErrorException();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**.env file**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
DB_DATABASE=orokopo
JWT_SECRET=secret_jwt
```

I wanted to build this project using all the new best pratices so i used the fancy "config way" instead of plain .env and ormconfig.json file. The same goes for using migrations and validating with joi.

Comment: Please add the complete error message to the post

Comment: Can you share UsersRepository code?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: I fixed  this. I can start the database. Now the problem is that i can't run migrations! It says this: TypeORMError: No connection options were found in any orm configuration files.